# How to add something at the beginning of every Bash command?

Tags: linux, bash

I'd like to change my Bash configuration, so when I type something (e.g. `foo bar`) in the command prompt, it really executes `h foo bar`.

I want to do it because I often use [hilite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hilite/) (aliased as `h`) to color stderr in red, and I would like to make this behaviour permanent.

Other use I see would be interacting with Git, as I write lots of commands like:

```
git status
git add ...
git commit ...
```

I guess I could use `preexec_invoke_exec` to execute something before
the command is being run, but I don't know how can I change the
command or prevent it from executing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this thread](http://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command)

Comment: Also have a look at [this thread](http://serverfault.com/questions/59262/bash-print-stderr-in-red-color)

Comment: @rody_o, I've seen both of them. It's not the same question - I know how to execute something before the command using `preexec_invoke_exec`. But here I also need a way to prevent Bash from running the command typed at prompt (as I want to run a different one).

Comment: m01 - Bash doesn't have a preexec like zsh, so you're out of luck unless you use the hack at rody_o's link.   And @rody_o - put these in an answer, increase your SO score!  :)

Comment: This would be possible, but a bad idea. It would break so many different things. For this particular application (coloring stderr red) I'd recommend something like [stderred](https://github.com/sickill/stderred).

Comment: Thedward: nice! I would accept this answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by binding the `return` key to insert the `h` for you. You can do this by adding this to your `.input.rc`:

```
Return: "\C-ah\ \n"
```

or put this `bind` in your `.bashrc`:

```
bind 'RETURN: "\C-ah \n"'
```

(Kudos to [these guys](https://superuser.com/questions/117227/a-command-before-every-bash-command)).

There are a few catches: obviously, it's bash-only, and this can give some pretty strange behavior in places (I can't think of a decent example right now), so I wouldn't say this is 'good' bashing in any way.

I would personally skip `hilite` and keep it all pure `bash`. So instead, try to look for a way to *append* something to each command so as to redirect the `stderr` stream to a colorized `echo`/`printf`...but that's a matter of preference I guess :)

Comment: +1!  Nice find!  It's terminal dependent, but should still suffice for 99.9% of folks who actually want to do this.  BTW, I agree that this should be kept in bash if possible.  Perhaps the OP should switch to ZSH?  :-)

Comment: If hacking your shell is the game: yup :)

Answer (score 0):

To run a different command from the one you've specified, your best bet may be to maks a bash function of the commands to be caught.

I don't know anything about "hilite", but if it installs a binary, at, say `/usr/bin/hilite`, you could use:

```
git () {
  /usr/bin/hilite /usr/bin/git "$@"
}
```

So ... when you run `git` at your bash prompt, bash will actually run `hilite`, using `/usr/bin/git` and the rest of your command line arguments as the arguments to `h`.

Note that this should work in traditional Bourne shell as well as bash.

Comment: Nice, but this doesn't solve the problem. I want `h` to be run for **all** the commands, not just git. I gave git only as an alternative example.